# Moving circle around ellipse

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I dont get it, how i can move circle around ellipse? elipse coords must be typed by the user, and it changes every time, how can i do that circle will always circle around ellipse? i know my code is wrong, it only moves around circle, but i need ellipse , this is only prototype.

```
import tkinter as tk
from math import cos, sin, radians

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background="black")
canvas.pack(fill="both",expand=True)

image = tk.PhotoImage(file="unnamed.png").subsample(7,7)

x2= int(input('enter radius x :'))
y2= int(input('enter radius y:'))
def create_circle(x, y, r, canvasName):
    x0 = x - r
    y0 = y - r
    x1 = x + r
    y1 = y + r

    return canvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1, outline = 'red')

def move(angle):
    if angle >=360:
        angle = 0
    x = 200 * cos(radians(angle))
    y = 200 * sin(radians(angle))
    angle+=1
    canvas.coords(circle, x2+x, y2+y)
    root.after(10, move, angle)
    
create_circle (x2,y2,200,canvas)
circle = canvas.create_image(200,100,image=image)

root.after(10, move, 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You want something to move (be redrawn) after the window is displayed?

Comment: i want it to move automatically without stopping, but only around ellipse.

Comment: You might find this answer helpful (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22064/calculating-a-point-that-lies-on-an-ellipse-given-an-angle) defines the equation for the points on an ellipse given the angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inbuilt method to acheive this. So, you must do your own calculation.

circle in tkinter is defined by (x1, y1, x2, y2) that is a rectangle(or square).

Here is an image that explains how a circle is drawn in tkinter and how to find `(x, y)`

[image]

theta in the above image is angle

Here `(s, t)` is defined by the equation `(x2-x1)/2` and `(y2-y1)/2` respectively

Here is a demonstration from your previous code (before you edited your code).:

```py
from tkinter import *
import math

x = 10
y = 10
a = 50
b = 50
t = 0

radius = 50 #radius around the circle

x_vel = 5
y_vel = 5

def move():

    global x, y, x_vel, y_vel, t, radius

    if x < 0:
        x_vel = 5
    if x > 700:
        x_vel = -5
    if y < 0:
        y_vel = 5
    if y > 700:
        y_vel = -5

    
    canvas1.move(circle, x_vel, y_vel)

    rx, ry, rw, rh = canvas1.coords(circle)
    
    rx1 = ((rw-rx)/2) +radius   # gets the s of the main circle
    ry1 = ((rh-ry)/2) +radius   # gets the t of the main circle


    cx = rx1*math.cos(t) + ry1*math.sin(t)
    cy = -rx1*math.sin(t) + ry1*math.cos(t)

    t += 1 # jump by how many degree
    

    if t > 360:
        t=0

    canvas1.moveto(rect2, cx+x, cy+y)

    x = rx
    y = ry
    
    window.after(33, move)
 
window   = Tk()
window.geometry("1000x1000")

canvas1=Canvas(window, height = 1000, width= 1000)
canvas1.grid (row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
coord = [x, y, a, b ]
circle = canvas1.create_oval(coord, outline="red", fill="red")
 
x0=  int(input("enter x center coord"))
y0= int(input("enter y center coord"))
coord = [x0, y0, y0, x0]
rect2 = canvas1.create_oval(coord, outline="Red", fill="")

move()
window.mainloop ()
```